# Threading issue with CocoaAsyncSocket and coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, gcdasyncsocket

My app handles socket connection in a background queue. Inside a helper class which will be called from the connection queue,  I have to access core data to perform a validation (fetch request). 
How can I execute the core data fetch in the main queue and pass the values to the connection queue?

The code is:

```
       -(void)getIsFavourite {
    //Execute the following codes in Main thread
            id <CHFavouriteUserDao>dao =[CHServiceRepository findService:@protocol(CHFavouriteUserDao)];
//findFavouriteUserByName will execute a fetch request and return a NSManagedObject
                FavouriteUser *user =  [dao findFavouriteUserByName:self.uniqueIdentifier];

    //Switch back to the background queue
                if (user!= nil) {
                    [self setIsFavourite:YES];
                }
```

1. I have tried the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:YES`. But it moves the socket execution to the main queue and freezes the app.
2. I tried dispatch_async with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, but the problem is how can I access the background queue which the socket connection is running (`dispatch_get_current_queue` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use NSOperationQueue? You can use

```
[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
```

and

```
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
```

and NSOperationQueue method – addOperations:waitUntilFinished: to wait for finishing operation.